# Integrate Coverity In jenkins

Tags: jenkins, coverity

I am new to coverity Static analysing tool. How to integrate Coverity in Jenkins and generate report in command prompt using coverity.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it looks like someone has already done that https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Coverity+Plugin Are you looking to run it from jenkins or from the commandline or both?

Comment: in both way i need to generate the report.

Comment: What is your Coverity Version.

Comment: documenting a thread about jenkins and coverity that just appeared on the jenkins users mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/62FRrpr5sIE